# XML error : Failed to load external entity in Zend Framework

Tags: xml, zend-framework

I want to read data from XML file but it showing the following errors:

Exception information:
Message:simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/common/xml/demo.xml"

Following is my code:

```
public function init() {
    require_once 'Zend/Config/Xml.php';
    $xml = new Zend_Config_Xml('/common/xml/demo.xml');        
    echo $xml;
}
```

Any solutions...thanx

Comment: Is /common/xml/demo.xml the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access /common/xml/demo.xml as an absolute path to a file.  Do you have a /common directory in your root?  Try getting rid of the first slash if what you mean is a relative path. If it's supposed to be a URL, add the full domain and http://...

If you really have a file with absolute /common/xml/demo.xml, you have to make sure apache has proper access permissions to that file at both a system file permission level and a apache configuration level (assuming you're not running this as a CLI script but serviing it as a site).

Comment: Yes you are right!! The problem was in path so I moved file to config folder and access it using $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/demo.xml');    Done!!! Thanks